# Best place to automatically add mode in xrandr

Tags: bash, ssh, 20.04, display-resolution, xrandr

What is the best place to add a mode with `xrandr`?

As of now, I added

```
xrandr --newmode "1344x744_60.00"   80.75  1344 1408 1544 1744  744 747 757 773 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1344x768_60.00"   84.00  1344 1416 1552 1760  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-2 "1344x744_60.00" 
xrandr --addmode DP-2 "1344x768_60.00"
```

to my `~/.bashrc`, but this is obviously not the best place, as every time I launch a bash process it tries to add modes.
So far, it only throws some errors (see below tl;dr), but it is harmless, I guess.

Perhaps `.gnomerc` is appropriate, although I guess if I start an xrdp session the mode may not be available.

Related:

1. [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120291/how-to-get-external-monitor-resolution-set-by-xrandr-to-persist

**EDIT**:
It seems `~/.xprofile` may be a good place for these settings.
I am not sure it works well with `vino-server`, which I need.

**EDIT 2**:
[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78324/137608) suggests using `~/.xinitrc`.
But it may be outdated.

---

**TL;DR**:
Errors I get:

1. When connecting from a text terminal (e.g., ssh)

   ```
      Can't open display
      Can't open display
      Can't open display
      Can't open display
   ```
2. When starting a graphic terminal when the modes were already added

   ```
      X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
        Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
        Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
        Serial number of failed request:  27
        Current serial number in output stream:  27
      X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
        Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
        Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
        Serial number of failed request:  27
        Current serial number in output stream:  27
   ```

Comment: Some discussion of this issue here: https://askubuntu.com/q/754231/57576

Comment: @andrew.46 - Thanks for the subtlety... I would say it is a dupe more than "Some discussion of this issue".
I will wait until my next opportunity to reboot (so it doesn't interfere with my work), and if the solution works as expected I would close this one as a duplicate.
Also relevant the link posted there
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently

Comment: @andrew.46 - Due to the pandemics I am working remotely, with `vino-server` and TigerVNC under Win10 as a client.
I had implemented the `.xprofile` method.
I just rebooted for the first time since this posting. At first I couldn't start a VNS session, and it turned out that `vino-server` did not start.
So I tried renaming `.xprofile`, rebooting, and now `vino-server` started, and I could start a VNC session as usual. Then I issued the commands from a terminal.

Comment: @andrew.46 - I am not certain about the causality, and I cannot test now; it can take a couple of hours of tinkering. I have no time, but above all I cannot risk losing VNC connectivity. In my experience, `vino-server` is somewhat fragile, and I have almost no access to the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using X11, you can add the mode to a config file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.  Name it something like `99-modes.conf`.

```
Section "Modes"
   Identifier "modes"
   Modeline "1368x768"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
EndSection
```

If the above doesn't work, you'll need to expand the config.

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "monitor"
   Modeline "1368x768"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "card"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "screen"
   Device "card"
   Monitor "monitor"
   SubSection "Display"
    Modes "1368x768"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

See also:

- ArchWiki: [Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg)
- [`man xorg.conf`](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml)